# table view, need to add a button to the top of the controller, when you click on the Add button. .

Tags: uitableview

hi guys have a table view, you need to **add a button to the top** of the controller, when you click on the Add button to **turn the tables on a separate controller** in the cat can write, this information can be displayed on the main screen, I do not know how to do it?